# jQuery .is() for already clicked

Tags: jquery, indexing, toggle

I have a series of lists, when a list item is clicked the list is split in two and a paragraph element is inserted in between. This paragraph element is assigned a class based on the index of the list item that was clicked.

I now am trying to remove that paragraph element if the list item was previously clicked or if the paragraph contains a class the same as clicked item's index.

I can't seem to get my head around the .is() method needed to get this working. My selectors are pretty cumbersome but here's my .is() method:

```
if ($(this).is($(this).parent().parent().children('.'+index))) {
    alert('li alread clicked');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K4b8J/15/

---

JS:

```
$(".category_list.grid li").click(function () {
    var $uls = $(this).parent().parent().children("ul"); 
    var $lis =  $uls.find("li");
    // add second list
    if ($uls.length < 2) {
        var $newUl = $("<ul></ul>").insertAfter($uls);
        $uls = $uls.add($newUl);
    }

    var index = $lis.index(this);
    alert(index);
    //calculate how many lis fit per line
    var noPerLine = Math.floor($(".category_list.grid").width()/$(".category_list.grid li").outerWidth(true));
    //find index at end of line to cut
    var cutIndex = (Math.ceil((index+1)/noPerLine)*noPerLine)-1;
    // if last row make index last item
    if (cutIndex > ($lis.length-1)) {
        cutIndex = $lis.length-1;
    }
    alert(cutIndex);


    var $following = $lis.slice(cutIndex + 1); // get all following `li` elements

    // append all li elements up to the current one to the
    // first list
    $uls.eq(0).append($lis.slice(0, cutIndex + 1));

    if ($following.length > 0) {
       // append to second list
       $uls.eq(1).append($following);
    } else {
        // remove second list if empty
        $uls.eq(1).remove();
        $uls = $uls.eq(0);
    }

    // add a paragraph after the first list
    $('.preview').remove();
    // find if index already clicked
    if ($(this).is($(this).parent().parent().children('.'+index))) {
        alert('li alread clicked');
    }

    $('<p />', {'class': 'preview ' + index,text: 'Test'}).insertAfter($uls.eq(0));

});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="category_list grid">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="category_list grid">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="category_list grid">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{padding:0;margin:0}
.preview {clear:both; min-height: 10em; background: red;}
ul {clear:both;}
li {
  width: 5em;
  height: 3em;
  background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 1em;
    color: white;
}
.category_list {margin-bottom:2em; clear:both;}
```

---

Something like this makes more sense but I still cant get it working.

```
if ($(this).parent().siblings('.preview').is('.'+index)) {
        alert('li already clicked');
    }
```

It appears that `$(this).parent().siblings('.preview')` makes some sort of array of '.previews' rather than selecting the only existing .'preview' from within the div.

---

Ok this works:

```
if ($(this).parent().next('.preview').is('.'+index)) {
        alert('li already clicked');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($(this).parent().next('.preview').is('.'+index)) {
        alert('li already clicked');
}
```

Works & the the if statement should go before you remove the paragraph element.
http://jsfiddle.net/K4b8J/19/